# Add specific anchors under posts title

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I'm new in wordpress plugins development , I'd like to create a plugin do some special edits on posts after created. I want to add a link (anchor) under the post after created (like in the attached image) to redirect to the new page that I will create ..

Can I do something like this?

[image: Wordpress]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a hook for [post_row_actions](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post_row_actions-in-34) filter

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'wpse8170_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function wpse8170_row_actions( $actions, WP_Post $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'my-custom-post-type' ) {
        return $actions;
    }

    $actions['wpse8170-pdf'] = 'http://your/url/here';
    return $actions;
}
```

Read this

http://pippinsplugins.com/add-custom-links-to-user-row-actions/

or read this one

http://www.codeforest.net/add-custom-links-to-row-actions-in-wordpress

Comment: Wow-- great filter .. never saw it before .. +1